# Como parsear JSOn

Tags: jquery, json

Hola me pudieran ayudar a parsear este JSON ya que no logro

```
{
  "pages": [
    {
      "name": "página1",
      "elements": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "pregunta1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

var obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj.pages.name);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pages`  es un array, no un objeto, Tienes que acceder  los elementos de pages por si indice:

```js
var json = '{ "pages": [ { "name": "página1", "elements": [ { "type": "text", "name": "pregunta1" } ] } ] }';

var data = JSON.parse(json);

for(var i = 0; i < data.pages.length;i++)
{
  console.log(data.pages[i].name);
}
```

Si lo que quieres es acceder al primer elemento entonces acceder al indice 0:

```js
var json = '{ "pages": [ { "name": "página1", "elements": [ { "type": "text", "name": "pregunta1" } ] } ] }';
var primeraPagina = JSON.parse(json).pages[0];

console.log(primeraPagina.name);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, sabia que tenia que recorrer nuevamente por el array pero no sabia exactamente como. Te agradezco mucho. Saludos

Comment: @kontramundo Si te ayudo la respuesta, puedes marcarla como la aceptada.